# trying to update split() to explode()

Tags: php, split, explode

I know very little PHP and I am trying to update code that was written for PHP 5.6 to 7.4.11

From what I understand split() does not work with PHP 7.4.11

I am trying to update the following 5 snips of code where split() is used.

- I have already tried changing the word out with `explode` and `preg_split` but those do not seem to fix the code.

`$arrscreenshots = split("\|", $uploadclass->screenshots);`

`. ' arrid = e.id.split("_");'`

`. ' var id = e.split("_")[1];'`

`. ' var arr = e.split("_");'`

`. ' var myarr = rows[rows.length-1].id.split("_");'`

Comment: Lines 2-5 are JS, not PHP.

Comment: would those need to be changed because the top part of those lines looks something like this `$output .= 'var helpmessage;' . 'function chkradios(e)'`

Comment: No. Your code is building a JS string within PHP, but the `split` on those lines is still JS.

Comment: so only line 1 needs to be updated is how im understanding things

Comment: Of those lines you posted, yes, only the 1st needs to be updated. You can use `explode` almost as a drop-in replacement, the only difference is that you don't need to escape the pipe character: `$arrscreenshots = explode("|", $uploadclass->screenshots);`

Comment: Thanks, thats a great help

Comment: If you submit that as the answer id be happy to accept it so you get the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines 2-5 are not PHP, they're JavaScript. (Even though they're created by PHP code, they're still being run as JavaScript by the browser.)

Line 1 can be changed to use `explode()`, which doesn't take a regular expression, so you can just use the delimiter directly:

```
$arrscreenshots = explode("|", $uploadclass->screenshots);
```

Or `preg_split()` which does take a regular expression, so you need to format the delimiter appropriately:

```
$arrscreenshots = preg_split("/\|/", $uploadclass->screenshots);
```

See https://3v4l.org/pv4Qb